# gparted live CD won't move/resize unmounted partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, gparted

GParted live will not allow me to resize/move partition /dev/sdb5:

[image: GParted]

No other windows (such as error dialogs) appear.  The partition is part of a RAID device, but I stopped all raid devices before starting GParted:

[image: stop raid]

The partition is not mounted:

[image: mount]

The partition table, as shown by fdisk:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3bdc0f91

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb2             2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5  *    1174409216 1886412799  712003584 339.5G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb6       1886414848 1953523711   67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
```

The fdisk "verify" command reports no errors:

```
Command (m for help): v
Remaining 1174412717 unallocated 512-byte sectors.
```

Misc:

- GParted Live 0.22.0-1-i586
- The swap device is not mounted (verified with `swapon -s`)
- I have tried removing the boot and raid flags from that partition.  That didn't help.

**Why won't GParted Live move/resize this unmounted partition?**

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the partition is not mounted, but the salient attribute is that the partition is formatted as linux-raid.  GParted cannot manipulate a linux-raid partition.  See http://gparted.org/features.php